# Require JS with regular functions

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I've just started out with requireJS and I wonder how can I access regular methods that needs jQuery.

Let's say I've this method called : displayError,

how can I call it since it's not in the global scope anymore.

I tried setting it to the window with:

window.displayError = function(message){
  ...
}

But that didn't work either.

Code looks like this:

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
window.show_save_state = function(state, message, time)
    {
        $(".save-state").remove();
        var save_state = $("<div />").addClass("save-state").appendTo("body");
        var newMessage = "";
        switch (state) {
            case 0:
                newMessage = lang("error");
                save_state.addClass("error");
                break;
            case 1:
                newMessage = lang("wait");
                save_state.addClass("wait");
                break;
            case 2:
                newMessage = lang("saved");
                save_state.addClass("saved");
                break;
        }
        var mMessage = (typeof message !== "undefined" && message != "") ? message : newMessage;
        save_state.html("<span class='save-state-circle'>" + mMessage + "</span>");
        save_state.show();
        time = (typeof time !== "undefined") ? time : 2000;
        time = (typeof message === "undefined" && state == 1) ? 0 : time;
        if (time > 0) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                save_state.fadeOut(200, function() {
                    save_state.remove();
                })
            }, time);
        }
    }
    window.hide_save_state = function() {
        $(".save_state").remove();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pQUBZ/

Comment: Setting `window.displayError` should work in terms of setting a global, but the basic idea with RequireJS/AMD is that you shouldn't need to do this. Can you show more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the primary purposes of using require is to keep crap out of the global namespace.  Let's say you have a file `con.js` where you keep your console display messages (including `displayError`) that looks like this:

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function(
    $
) {
    var con = {
        displayError: function (message) {
            // ...code...
        },

        displaySomethingElse: function (foo) {
            // ...code...
        }
    };

    return con;
});
```

Then in its most basic form you could run this method via a require statement as follows:

```
require('con').displayError('Move every zig!');
```

Or within another submodule like:

```
define([
    "con"
], function(
    con
) {
    var submodule = {
        someMethod: function () {
            con.displayError('Watership Down');
        }
    };

    return submodule;
});
```